# How to correctly use Plotly's `@app.callback` function?

Tags: python, callback, plotly

I am using Plotly to display several data sets that are connected to another. When the user clicks on a point in the main plot the three sub plots are changed accordingly as is shown in this gif:

[image: Demo of connected plots]

This is done using Plotly's `@app.callback` function like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('mesh', 'figure'),
    [Input('overview', 'clickData')])
def update_figure(clickData):
    selected_Re = clickData['points'][0]['x']
    curve_number = clickData['points'][0]['curveNumber']
    trace_name = forces_dict.keys()[curve_number]
    return {
       'data': getMeshTraces(trace_name,selected_Re),
       'layout': go.Layout(
            title='Mesh study for Re = '+str(selected_Re)+' ('+trace_name+')',
            xaxis={'title': 'No. of faces'},
            yaxis={'title': selected_force},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }
```

Although this seems to work fine, when starting the app it throws an type error that the `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. I believe this is caused because in the beginning no point is selected and thus the variable `clickData` is empty. However when I tried to prevent this error by putting everything `def update_figure(clickData):` inside an if statement

```
if clickData is not None:
```

this actually broke the functionality and the app is not working anymore. Alternatively I also tried to put everything inside a `try:` statement, but that yielded the same result. It seems like `update_figure` is only evaluated once when the app is started and the result of the `if` or `try` statement is then seen as static.

How can I clean up my code, i.e. getting rid of the error message and still remain the functionality that it has right now?

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @rpanai, thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I will not have access to the project until next Wednesday. I will then update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached the same issue than you that I solved with this:

```
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

into callback function:

    if clickData is None:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

Please check:
http://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks